# Automatic Sorting on Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to sort my sheet alphabetically automatically. Whenever I put a new entry under columns A-C, I would like it to automatically sort together with the rest of the data.

I've heard that this must be done using Google apps scripts. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XH4mrKa6W4se5WwM6oKqh959gG2kAQVtAmOnml13VoE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 51):

Spreadsheets are easy to sort from a script and a script can easily be triggered by a spreadsheet "event".

`onEdit` is one of these events that should fit your demand. [Doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit()) 
and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound).

then the sort process is [shown in the doc,](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)) I reproduce the code below :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C7");

 // Sorts by the values in the first column (A)
 range.sort(1);

 // Sorts by the values in the second column (B)
 range.sort(2);

 // Sorts descending by column B
 range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});

 // Sorts descending by column B, then ascending by column A
 // Note the use of an array
 range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);

 // For rows that are sorted in ascending order, the "ascending" parameter is
 // optional, and just an integer with the column can be used instead. Note that
 // in general, keeping the sort specification consistent results in more readable
 // code. We could have expressed the earlier sort as:
 range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}, 1]);

 // Alternatively, if we wanted all columns to be in ascending order, we would use
 // the following (this would make column 2 ascending)
 range.sort([2, 1]);
 // ... which is equivalent to
 range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
```

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158165/27487 is a public workbook I made with a script to demo how to do this in an easily-configurable way.

Answer (score 1):

This might have been updated as I could not get the top answer to work.  Here is what I was able to use.

Where you reverse the order of priority:  In this example column 2 is the highest priority and column 3 is the secondary sort.

```
const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.sort(3).sort(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create function and sort by column name. Enter the column name as a string when invoking the function.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F30");
var values = range.getValues();

var sortByCol = function Sort(sort) {
      var sort = sort.toLowerCase();
      for (var i=1; i <= range.getNumColumns(); i++) {
        if (String(values[0][i]).toLowerCase() === sort) {
          range.sort({column: i+1, ascending: false});
           break;
        }
      }  
}
```