# Google Sheets script to sort entire sheet in descending order

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a function which sorts the sheet DATA by column 4, in descending order,

```
function specialSort(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DATA');
  sheet.sort({ column: 4, ascending: false })
}
```

Other answers (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563652/automatic-sorting-on-sheets)) seem to recommend this approach. But why does this code throw the error `Exception: Cannot convert '[object Object]' to int`? If I instead use simply `sheet.sort(4)`, I get the result I want (sorting the whole sheet by column 4), except that it's in ascending order.

Note well: I want to (descending) sort the whole sheet by column 4, not just the column itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your script, I thought that `sort(sortSpecOb)` is for Class Range. The arguments of `sort(columnPosition, ascending)` of Class Sheet are `columnPosition`(Integer), `ascending`(Boolean). I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function specialSort() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DATA');
  sheet.sort(4, false);
}
```

#### References:

- [sort(columnPosition, ascending) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sortcolumnposition,-ascending)
- [sort(sortSpecOb of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)